# Can't make button visible property to true

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on VB.NET

I have a form created with (among other things) a panel and some buttons in it.

The default visible property value is true for the buttons. However when I launch the form, they are invisible.

I investigated and found that in the code generated by the designer, the buttons are visible when added to the panel, and when adding the panel to the main form, they become invisible.

Here is a preview of my code:

```
'ActionsPanel is the panel which contains the buttons
Me.ActionsPanel.Controls.Add(Me.SaveButton)
Me.ActionsPanel.Controls.Add(Me.DeleteButton)
Me.ActionsPanel.Controls.Add(Me.NewButton)
Me.ActionsPanel.Controls.Add(Me.OpenButton)
'So far the buttons are visible

Me.Controls.Add(Me.ActionsPanel)
'Me refers to the parent form of the controls
'As of here the buttons become invisible
```

So, in the line where the Panel is added to the form, the buttons become invisible.

I'm trying to force them to true using the debugger just for test but the property doesn't change (See video cast : [Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xwp3i9dfs91bkrh/2013-11-02%2019h50_18.mp4).

Does anyone have an idea please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Change their visible values in the designer to true.

Comment: It's already the case. Their values in the designer are true

Comment: Nice video. Have you tried to set true after Add(Me.ActionsPanel)?

Comment: Is there anywhere you have set them to false in code? right click on the `Visible` property and `Find All Occurrences` if you need to locate all code where this could have changed.

Comment: Is the panel visible true?

Comment: Are you sure the panel is loading where you want it? You need to check out it's location and the buttons' locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Me.ActionsPanel.Controls.Add(Button1)
```

Instead of

```
Me.ActionsPanel.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
```

Hope this helps.

Also If you want to move it around, use

```
Button1.Location = New Point(X, Y)
```

Answer (score 3):

I got a similar problem today (though I can't see the video anymore) and in my specific case, the problem was that I set the visible property of a control that is child of another control.

If I did `child.visible=true` and then `if child.visible`, the result was `false`.

What I found is that if I then set `parent.visible=true` then `child.visible` also becomes `true`. In fact, it looks like the child controls only report their defined state if the parent is visible.

Hope this could help some people even if this thread is over 2 years old.

Answer (score 0):

```
'ActionsPanel is the panel which contains the buttons
Me.ActionsPanel.Controls.Add(Me.SaveButton)
Me.ActionsPanel.Controls.Add(Me.DeleteButton)
Me.ActionsPanel.Controls.Add(Me.NewButton)
Me.ActionsPanel.Controls.Add(Me.OpenButton)
```

This shows you adding buttons from a form to the panel.  Since you do not change the location, there is a high liklihood that they are not in the visible area.  It is not that the visible Property is False, but they are not viewable or cannot be seen.  It keeps changing back, because they are not in the viewable area.

```
dim btn as Button = Me.SaveButton
Me.ActionsPanel.Controls.Add(btn)
btn.Location = new point (10,10)      ' maybe other properties too

btn = Me.DeleteButton
Me.ActionsPanel.Controls.Add(btn)
btn.Location = new point (10,40)
```